# How to select specific part of JSON and convert it to a List in retrofit with Moshi

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

I'm getting the JSON blow from an API with retrofit and I want to only select the **production_companies array** from it and convert it to a list of ProductionCompanie class, how I can do it with Moshi **without using nested classes**?

```json
{
    "backdrop_path": "/52AfXWuXCHn3UjD17rBruA9f5qb.jpg",
    "belongs_to_collection": null,
    "budget": 63000000,
    "genres": [
        {
            "id": 18,
            "name": "Drama"
        }
    ],
    "homepage": "http://www.foxmovies.com/movies/fight-club",
    "id": 550,
    "popularity": 40.054,
    "poster_path": "/8kNruSfhk5IoE4eZOc4UpvDn6tq.jpg",
    "production_companies": [
        {
            "id": 508,
            "logo_path": "/7PzJdsLGlR7oW4J0J5Xcd0pHGRg.png",
            "name": "Regency Enterprises",
            "origin_country": "US"
        },
        {
            "id": 711,
            "logo_path": "/tEiIH5QesdheJmDAqQwvtN60727.png",
            "name": "Fox 2000 Pictures",
            "origin_country": "US"
        },
        {
            "id": 20555,
            "logo_path": "/hD8yEGUBlHOcfHYbujp71vD8gZp.png",
            "name": "Taurus Film",
            "origin_country": "DE"
        },
        {
            "id": 54051,
            "logo_path": null,
            "name": "Atman Entertainment",
            "origin_country": ""
        }
    ],
    "vote_count": 21181
}
```

this is my retrofit Apis interface:

```kotlin
interface Apis {

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @GET("/3/movie/550")
    fun getData(@Query("api_key") key: String = apiKey): Call<List<ProductionCompanie>>

}
```

and my model:

```kotlin
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class ProductionCompanie(
    @Json(name = "id")
    val id: Int,

    @Json(name = "logo_path")
    val picture: String,

    @Json(name = "name")
    val name: String
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Nested Classes"

Comment: You can write a custom JSON adaptor with Moshi for parsing only production_companies array from your json.

Comment: @MehdiYari can you show me a example for this?
I want to convert this list automaticlly

Comment: @ali-star Sorry, my solution is writing a class for parsing this JSON to a list of the production_companies with the `JsonAdapter` abstract class and does not seem to be the solution you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a custom adapter:

```kotlin
class ProductionCompanieListAdapter(private val moshi: Moshi) {

    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(value: JsonReader): List<ProductionCompanie>? {
        val json = JSONObject(value.nextSource().readUtf8())
        val jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("production_companies")
        val type = Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, ProductionCompanie::class.java)
        val adapter = moshi.adapter<List<ProductionCompanie>>(type)
        return adapter.fromJson(jsonArray.toString())
    }

    @ToJson
    fun toJson(value: List<ProductionCompanie>): String {
        val type = Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, ProductionCompanie::class.java)
        val adapter = moshi.adapter<List<ProductionCompanie>>(type)
        return adapter.toJson(value)
    }

}
```