# Custom Adapter to filter objects based on a parameter from an JSON response in Retrofit using Moshi

Tags: android, json, retrofit, moshi

I am getting an API response as below. The data field is an array of `Design` objects. I want to filter the contents based on `type` field into different lists.

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "typeA",
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "typeB",
    },
  ]
}
```

So basically I should be able to get a `HashMap<DesignType, List<Design>()`. The types are known before-hand.

This is my data class

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Design(
    val id: String,
    val type: DesignType
)
```

I have gone through some posts but haven't been able to find exactly what I need. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66386623/how-to-select-specific-part-of-json-and-convert-it-to-a-list-in-retrofit-with-mo) shows how to extract the list, but I need to filter the contents into different lists.

Comment: i'm traveling for the next week, so i can't write a code-complete answer now. but basically you could write a simple adapter that loops through your List<Data> and gives you your Map. look at the docs on how to make adapters.